# ubuntu vpn connection problem

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-10.04

i'm usign ubuntu linux and want to connect to vpn server. the vpn testet by windows and it's ok. but when i add into vpn connection my connection will be failed and these messages will appear.

```
Oct 28 15:48:35 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct 28 15:48:35 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct 28 15:48:35 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 28 15:48:35 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Oct 28 15:48:37 sweb-laptop kernel: [11695.582279] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55889 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:37 sweb-laptop kernel: [11695.583231] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=50 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55890 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:38 sweb-laptop kernel: [11696.700335] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55891 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:39 sweb-laptop kernel: [11697.967607] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55892 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:39 sweb-laptop kernel: [11698.285199] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55893 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:42 sweb-laptop kernel: [11700.720577] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55894 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:42 sweb-laptop kernel: [11700.976640] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55895 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:45 sweb-laptop kernel: [11703.977792] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55896 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:45 sweb-laptop kernel: [11704.220700] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55897 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:48 sweb-laptop kernel: [11706.974657] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55898 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:50 sweb-laptop kernel: [11709.005479] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55899 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:51 sweb-laptop kernel: [11709.988579] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55900 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:54 sweb-laptop kernel: [11712.977709] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55901 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:57 sweb-laptop kernel: [11715.984600] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55902 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:48:58 sweb-laptop kernel: [11716.676607] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55903 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:49:00 sweb-laptop kernel: [11718.984500] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55904 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:49:03 sweb-laptop kernel: [11721.983411] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55905 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 15:49:06 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Oct 28 15:49:06 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Connection terminated.
Oct 28 15:49:06 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Modem hangup
Oct 28 15:49:06 sweb-laptop pppd[12194]: Exit.
```

what's my problem.
i'm using ubuntu 10.04. thank you.

more log:

```
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 2781
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' just appeared, activating connections
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 1
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 3
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN connection 'MYVPN' (Connect) reply received.
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pptp[2787]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Oct 28 17:49:37 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Oct 28 17:49:38 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Oct 28 17:49:38 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Oct 28 17:49:38 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 32227).
Oct 28 17:49:39 sweb-laptop kernel: [  384.539890] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=50 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=970 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:39 sweb-laptop kernel: [  384.541902] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=969 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:40 sweb-laptop kernel: [  385.476953] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=971 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:41 sweb-laptop kernel: [  386.910951] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=972 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:41 sweb-laptop kernel: [  386.939756] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=973 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:43 sweb-laptop kernel: [  389.145950] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=974 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:44 sweb-laptop kernel: [  389.923891] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=975 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:47 sweb-laptop kernel: [  392.522791] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=976 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:47 sweb-laptop kernel: [  392.924007] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=977 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:50 sweb-laptop AptDaemon: INFO: Quiting due to inactivity
Oct 28 17:49:50 sweb-laptop AptDaemon: INFO: Shutdown was requested
Oct 28 17:49:50 sweb-laptop kernel: [  395.947167] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=978 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:52 sweb-laptop kernel: [  398.061898] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=979 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:53 sweb-laptop kernel: [  398.970317] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=980 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:56 sweb-laptop kernel: [  401.934104] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=981 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:49:59 sweb-laptop kernel: [  404.932978] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=982 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:50:01 sweb-laptop kernel: [  406.527102] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=983 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:50:02 sweb-laptop kernel: [  407.935283] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=984 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:50:05 sweb-laptop kernel: [  410.941308] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:24:e8:d8:43:21:00:22:2d:3b:e5:1d:08:00 SRC=69.175.70.158 DST=192.168.2.3 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=985 PROTO=47 
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Connection terminated.
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pptp[2787]: nm-pptp-service-2781 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Modem hangup
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pptp[2787]: nm-pptp-service-2781 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pptp[2794]: nm-pptp-service-2781 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop pppd[2783]: Exit.
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 6
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <WARN>  connection_state_changed(): Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Oct 28 17:50:08 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <info>  Policy set 'Home Network' (eth0) as default for routing and DNS.
Oct 28 17:50:20 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <debug> [1288275620.001374] ensure_killed(): waiting for vpn service pid 2781 to exit
Oct 28 17:50:20 sweb-laptop NetworkManager: <debug> [1288275620.001553] ensure_killed(): vpn service pid 2781 cleaned up
```

Comment: It may be that your firewall is rejecting the protocol 47 (GRE) traffic which is the encrypted connection.  Could you (a) confirm that 69.175.70.158 is the vpn server you're talking to, and (b) post the output of "iptables -L -n -v"?

Comment: I dont think problem is for firewall. see the updated log

Comment: With respect, if people are trying to help you, and ask for some output from X to test a hypothesis, it's not helpful for you to say "I don't think it's an X problem".  What you have posted makes me very suspicious about the firewall, but before I ask you to change anything I need to see what your current ruleset is, which is what "iptables -L -n -v" does.  If you don't want to tell me, that's fine - but please just say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent your firewall config, I still strongly suspect that you're not accepting the GRE traffic which constitutes the VPN's encapsulation format.  Try

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p 47 -s 69.175.70.158 -j ACCEPT
```

to accept GRE traffic from your VPN peer.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked, and thanks for coming back and letting me know!  But please, I urge you, next time you post a question here and someone asks for diagnostic output, do consider that they might have an insight into the problem that you don't yet have, and then you'll learn from what they post.  On the other hand, sometimes I ask dumb follow-up questions, and I'm wrong about the causes of an issue, and then *I* learn from what *you* post.  Information is win-win!